# Finding sums of all subarrays of an array

Tags: arrays, sliding-window, sub-array, maximumslidingwindow

This is a snippet from this code to finding sums of all subarrays of a given array, but this doesn't work as intended as the problem seems to be lying with pre-incrementing value of i in the equation.

```
while(i<vec.size()-1){
  sum += -vec[i-2] + vec[++i] ;
  nums.emplace_back(sum);
}
return nums;
```

However, when i deploy this code which seems to be the same implementation as the previous one, the code runs correctly:

```
while(i<vec.size()-1){
  sum += -vec[i-2] + vec[i+1] ;
  nums.emplace_back(sum);
  i++;
}
```

Please Clarify!

I tried it on: (1,2,3,4,)
Expected: 6,9,12
Output from 1st snippet: 6,8,10   //Incorrect
Output from 2nd snippet: 6,9,12   //Correct

Comment: Share the data format of the arrays... and What language are you using?

Comment: Why does your expected output only have 3 values? An array of 4 elements has 10 subarrays ... And how would you get a sum of `12`, when all elements in the array only sum up to 10?

Comment: The code is written in C++. 
The data format: vector<int> (if thats what you asked)
And sorry the input array is: 1,2,3,4,5 and not 1,2,3,4, (mistake on my part, its my first question ever :_) )
Thanks for your response..